# Printing a selection of a JSON array data out to a page using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Not having much luck with a tricky JSON object and getting it to write certain data into a HTML page. I am attempting to target only particular sets of data in the array - not the whole array. I have got no control over how the JSON object/data is being presented unfortunately.

Here is what I have done:

```
    <script>
    var response={
  "bookings": {
    "group_id": 12306,
    "name": "Public Meeting Rooms",
    "url": "http:\/\/slqpub.libcal.com\/rooms.php?i=12306",
    "timeslots": [{
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Mahjong",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T10:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Mahjong",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Mahjong",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T13:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Jo Tindall and Sagarika",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T14:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T15:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Jo Tindall and Sagarika",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T15:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T16:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "James Math",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T16:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T17:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "James Math",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T17:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T18:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "James Math",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T18:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T19:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "IELTS",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T10:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "recording",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "recording",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T13:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "IELTS",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T13:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T14:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "IELTS",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T15:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T16:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "Luke",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T16:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T17:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "Luke",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T17:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T18:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "Luke",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T18:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T19:00:00+10:00"
    }],
    "last_updated": "2016-01-20T12:40:36+10:00"
  }
}

    </script> 

    <table border="1">
    <tr><th>Room Name</th><th>Booked by</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 2A</td><td><span id="room_bookings2a"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 2B</td><td><span id="room_bookings2b"></span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 4B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 4A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 3E</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 3D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 3C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 3B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 3A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 2D</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 2C</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 2B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Meeting Room 4D</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Right now, it only prints out the last item in the array, not all the data between nodes 0-7.

EDIT: Was not too bright inserting a live API feed from a link so I have cut and paste the JSON data into this question.

Comment: Can you show us your JSON and be more specific about what you mean by *it only prints out the last item in the array, not all the data between nodes 0-7*?  What are you trying to accomplish with `.timeslots[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`?

Comment: The JSON data is way too big to post here. You can access it at https://api2.libcal.com/1.0/room_bookings_nickname/?iid=3356&group_id=12306&key=92a47e5c854dee620cca071648c3fc41 If you look at the 'timeslots' array in the console log you can see it has 81 instances. Basically I just want to print out all info for room 2A, If i go past a certain point in the array it prints data from the other rooms. This is the way the remote JSON feed has been constructed.

Comment: OK, will you need to do this for each room or just for this one room?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Then I will make a query for the next room and so forth. In the end, I want to print out information for each room via the HTML table. The JSON feed is just not my cup of tea at the moment.

Comment: But all of the info for all rooms is in the first JSON response correct?

Comment: I don't 100% understand your last question... yes I think so Here is a fiddle with the JSON data printed into it https://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/p92s3fb5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101144/discussion-between-ryan-coolwebs-and-delightedd0d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is first iterate the nested JSON and group together the information for each room like this:

```
// loop over the object and gather all the information for each room type  
var bookingsByRoom = {};
$.each(response.bookings.timeslots, function(i, timeslot) {
  var room = timeslot.room_name;
  if (bookingsByRoom[room]) bookingsByRoom[room].push(timeslot);
  else bookingsByRoom[room] = [timeslot];
});
/*
bookingsByRoom is now an object like:
{
  Meeting Room 2 A: {
    booking_end: "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00",
    booking_label: "Mahjong"
    booking_start: "2016-01-20T10:00:00+10:00"
    room_id: "36615"
    room_name: "Meeting Room 2A"
  }, {
    booking_end: "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00"
    booking_label: "Mahjong"
    booking_start: "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00"
    room_id: "36615"
    room_name: "Meeting Room 2A"
  }
}, 
{
  Meeting Room 2 B: ....
}

*/
```

Then you can loop over the newly created array and display whatever data you need.

[Here is a jsFiddle showing how you might further this to actually display your data.](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/a835vx3j/4/)

Comment: Thanks, it worked well, did not quite work out for me as my JSON feed only spits out filled slots and not empty slots. Need like a visual custom calendar visualisation to display the data. So I've taken the code a bit further but run into some new challenges http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914899/how-to-apply-custom-json-data-over-a-preformatted-html-page

Answer (score 1):

I made javascript code

```
// Using LibCal and JSONP
$.ajax({
url: "https://api2.libcal.com/1.0/room_bookings_nickname/?iid=3356&group_id=12306&key=92a47e5c854dee620cca071648c3fc41",

// The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
jsonp: "callback",

// Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
dataType: "jsonp",

// Work with the response
success: function( response ) {
        console.log(response);
    var data = response.bookings.timeslots;
    var room  = {};
    var roomInfo = {};

    $.each(data, function(index,element){
        if(typeof room[element.room_id] === "undefined"){
        room[element.room_id] = [];
        roomInfo[element.room_id] = element.room_name;
      }
      room[element.room_id].push(element);
    });




    for(var roomId in room){
        var dest = room[roomId];
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      tr.append($('<td>'+roomInfo[roomId]+'</td>'));
      var td = $('<td>');
      for(var i=0; i<dest.length; i++){
        var item = dest[i];
        var div = $('<div></div>');
        div.text(item.booking_label+" ["+item.booking_start+" : "+item.booking_end+"]");
        td.append(div);
      }

      tr.append(td);

      $("table").append(tr);
    }

}
});
```

[My Practice Code](https://jsfiddle.net/t1a85f2n/1/)