# How to apply custom JSON data over a preformatted HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON feed that displays room bookings for multiple rooms.
The problem is that it only shows the timeslots that are booked and does not show empty slots/appointments in the data object. My first attempt at this was this question [Printing a selection of a JSON array data out to a page using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890551/printing-a-selection-of-a-json-array-data-out-to-a-page-using-jquery) and it does not show empty timeslots.

Ok so I came up with an idea to have a preformatted HTML 'template' page with some data already present - effectively to overlay the JSON data in the booked timeslots and leave the empty timeslots as just static HTML.

The 'simplified' JSON file (just a selection of whole object):

```
var response={
  "bookings": {
    "group_id": 12306,
    "name": "Public Meeting Rooms",
    "url": "http:theurlfeed.from.libcal",
    "timeslots": [{
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Mahjong",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T10:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36615",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2A",
      "booking_label": "Mahjong",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "IELTS",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T10:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T11:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "recording",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T12:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T13:00:00+10:00"
    }, {
      "room_id": "36616",
      "room_name": "Meeting Room 2B",
      "booking_label": "Luke",
      "booking_start": "2016-01-20T18:00:00+10:00",
      "booking_end": "2016-01-20T19:00:00+10:00"
    }],
    "last_updated": "2016-01-20T12:40:36+10:00"
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML (for the sake of simplification I haven't shown the complete structure):

```
<table border="1" id="rooms-table">
<thead><tr><th></th>&nbsp;<th>10am</th><th>11am</th><th>12pm</th><th>1pm</th><th>2pm</th><th>3pm</th><th>4pm</th><th>5pm</th><th>6pm</th><th>7pm</th></tr></thead>
<tbody id="main-table-body">
  <tr>
    <td>Meeting Room 2A</td>
    <td class="36615 10:00"></td>
    <td class="36615 11:00"></td>
    <td class="36615 12:00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Meeting Room 2B</td>
    <td class="36616 10:00"></td>
    <td class="36616 11:00"></td>
    <td class="36616 12:00"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

And this is my JavaScript (contains pseudo code for concepts i cannot yet code):

```
    //Convert timestamp to readable format and remove date
    var Timeslots = response.bookings.timeslots;

    function getTime(timestamp) {
        var time = new Date(timestamp);
        return [ time.getHours(), time.getMinutes() ].map(function(time){
            return ['', "0"][+(String(time).length < 2)] + String(time);
        }).join(':');
    }                  

    for(var i in Timeslots) (function(Timeslots){
        Timeslots.booking_start = getTime(Timeslots.booking_start);
        Timeslots.booking_end = getTime(Timeslots.booking_end);
    })(Timeslots[i]);

    console.log(response);

    var roomList = new Array;
    var tdClassList;

    //function to detect if timeslot is booked or not
    //If booked, assigns the booking name and changes bg color of cell
    $.each(response.bookings.timeslots, function(index, timeslot) {

        var roomBooking = timeslot.room_id + ' ' + timeslot.booking_start;
        roomList[roomBooking] = roomBooking;

        tdClassList = $('td').map(function () {
            return $(this).attr('class');
        }).get();

    });
    console.log(tdClassList);
    console.log(roomList);
         // This code is incomplete
         // It will need to loop through both arrays and compare values and then write some css and html if match is found across the arrays
        /*if (roomList == tdClassName) {
            $( "td" ).html(timeslot.booking_label)
            $( "td" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
        } else { $( "td" ).html("");
        }*/
```

}

My JS code needs quite a bit of work, brain is struggling with it. Can I please ask for some 'best practice' suggestions?

Comment: You might want to use http://handlebarsjs.com/, that might do the job for you. As you are constructing HTML from JSON.

Comment: Need to be far more specific about where your problems are ... `brain struggling` while understandable isn't a proper problem description

Comment: Ok @charlietfl, I will put it in simple plain english.
My idea is to loop through data array in JSON and then match up the current bookings with the cells in the table via their class (using unique identifier class which is a combination of the room_id and booking_start data. The code looks through the JSON and when it finds a booked timeslot, it then writes it's 'booking_label' data into the TD cell and changes the css bg.

Comment: @Jeremy Rajan, thanks for the mention about handlebars. I'm going to try to achieve it in jQuery JS first before I go down that path. I have edit the code so now I get arrays of class names